# Write to Settings Data Json in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have custom values that I am using a page with a custom template to access and modify. These values are saved in the settings.dat json file but I do not want to use the editor created by the schema to modify it.

Is there a solution to add/edit values to the settings.data json file using a liquid file?

Comment: No there is no way to modify them from a liquid file without a use of a 3rd party app.

Comment: You can use the asset api of shopify admin instead but I do not think this is doable by liquid codes.